# работа с socks5/4

Tags: c#

http/https прокси я использую так:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
WebProxy proxy = new Webproxy(host,port);
req.Proxy = proxy;
HttpWebRespone res = req.GetWebResponse();
```

Но с socks5/4 не удается получить Respone. Постоянно ошибка("Tor is not Http proxy"). Собственно вопрос: "какой класс поддерживает работу с socks5?"

Socks беру от TorBrowser.

Comment: curl, например, прекрасно работает с socks-proxy. А уж какой там класс я не знаю.

Comment: Посмотри http://jonxxx.me/15-dotnet/24-socks-proxy-na-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122369/use-webclient-with-socks-proxy

Comment: Спасибо, но WebClient не всегда устраивает.

Comment: в древние времена tor шел с прокси polipo, к которому можно было обращаться по http. Потом на его место вроде бы пришел privoxy, а полипо стало не найти. Вот к этим проксям и нужно обращаться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для тех кто ищет. Самый простой способ это воспользоваться библиотекой [xNet](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet)

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.Proxy = ProxyClient.Parse(ProxyType.Socks5, "host:port");
var respone = req.Get("Https://google.com").ToString();
```